# C# Unit test contol invoke issue

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I've written an unit test for a WinForms app. The app executes a code in a thread which sets on UI a result. For that I have to invoke the result set in the UI thread by `Control.Invoke(delegate)`. In the app it works perfect. In the unit test I have to wait for the async result. But, in the unit test the `Control.Invoke(delegate)` doesn't fire.

I have no threading issue. Threads work perfect in the unit test. The issue is the invoke on UI thread form a thread. Does anybody have a hint, how it works.

For reproduce this issue I have created a sample WinForms project and a unit test project. The Form contains a textbox and a button. By click on the button it starts a thread, waits for two seconds and sets a text in the textbox. After setting the text it fires an event.

This is the Forms class:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetText();
    }

    public delegate void delFinish();
    public event delFinish Finish;

    public void SetText()
    {      
        Thread runner = new Thread(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            if (this.txtResult.InvokeRequired)
                this.txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    this.txtResult.Text = "Runner";

                    if (Finish != null)
                        Finish();
                }));
            else
            {
                this.txtResult.Text = "Runner";

                if (Finish != null)
                    Finish();
            }

        });
        runner.Start();
    }
}
```

This is the unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        ManualResetEvent finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);  

        TestForm form = new TestForm();

        form.Finish += () => {
            finished.Set();
        };

        form.SetText();

        Assert.IsTrue(finished.WaitOne());

        Assert.IsTrue(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form.txtResult.Text));
    }
}
```

The problem is this line which will not execute:

```
              this.txtResult.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Application.Run() is missing.  Required to get Invoke() to do its job.

Comment: Application.Run() is not the problem. I don't need a window for the test.

Comment: Hmya, very pointless to run tests like this.  But of course you are mistaken, that form *did* create a window, its InvokeRequired property is *true*.  You'll also see its IsHandleCreated property set to *true*.  A window requires Application.Run() to be functional.  If you believe that it shouldn't then declare "test failed" and write a bug report for the developer.  He won't take kindly to that bug report but at least try to figure out why his constructor gets the window created.  It isn't the most healthy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that in the above sample the current thread is blocked but on this thread the control wants to invoke.

The solution is to to other events Application.DoEvents() and yield execution to another thread Thread.Yield().

The test method look like:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        bool finished = false;

        TestForm form = new TestForm();

        form.Finish += () =>
        {
            finished = true;
        };

        form.SetText();

        while (!finished)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Yield();
        }                         

        Assert.IsTrue(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form.txtResult.Text));
    }
```

Hope this helps for somebody.